# babelJs Angular & lite-server, how compile ES6 ?

Tags: npm, babeljs, lite-server

For my project Angular I use lite-server .
I want to use Es6 JS for my project with Babel.

How I can compilme my sources with lite-server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using webpack now ! ans ESLint